# Taken to top of content when using ngFor inside an ngIf

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor, angular-ng-if, ion-infinite-scroll

I have a reorder section inside a food ordering app, the orders are paginated from backend and are loaded using ion-inifite-scroll. I have two buttons which show me delivered orders and upcoming orders. The data for both sections is displayed using *ngFor which is inside an *ngIf. When scrolled to the bottom of the section ion-infinite-scroll pushes more data into the array used in the ngFor, but as soon as the data is pushed I am taken to the top of content.

HTML code:

```
<ng-content>

<!-- buttons -->
  <button (click)="pastOrDelivered(false)">
    Upcoming Orders
  </button>

  <button (click)="pastOrDelivered(true)">
    Delivered Orders
  </button>

<!-- upcoming orders -->
  <div *ngIf="showUpcoming">
    <div *ngFor="let order of upcoming; let i=index;">
      <div class="item-card item-card-bottom">
        <h4>upcoming data</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- delivered orders -->
  <div *ngIf="showDelivered">
    <div *ngFor="let order of delivered; let i=index;">
      <div class="item-card item-card-bottom">
        <h4>delivered data</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<ion-infinite-scroll threshold="30%" position="bottom" [disabled]="!shouldGetOrders" (ionInfinite)="onIonInfinite($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner=""></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>

</ng-content>
```

Typescript:

```
class OrderHistoryPage {
  upcoming: any = [];
  orders: any = [];
  deliveredOrders: any[] = [];
  showDelivered: boolean = false; 
  showUpcoming: boolean = true;
  offset = 0;
  records = 10;
  shouldGetOrders = true;

  async ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.pastOrDelivered(true);
    this.getOrders();
  }

  async getOrders() {
    this.userAPI.getOrderHistory(this.offset, this.records)
    .subscribe((orders: any) => {
      if(orders.total >= this.records) {
        this.offset += this.records;
      } else {
        this.shouldGetOrders = false;
      }
      
      this.orders = orders.orders;

      this.orders.forEach( order => {
        if (order.deliveryStatus != 'DELIVERED' && order.deliveryStatus != 'CANCELLED') {
          this.upcoming.push(order)
        } else if (order.deliveryStatus == 'DELIVERED' || order.deliveryStatus == 'CANCELLED') {
          this.deliveredOrders.push(order)
        }
      });
      }, err => {});
  }

  onIonInfinite(ev) {
    if(this.shouldGetOrders === true) {
      this.getOrders();
      setTimeout(() => {
        (ev as InfiniteScrollCustomEvent).target.complete();
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  pastOrDelivered(params) {
    this.showDelivered = params
    this.showUpcoming = !params
  }

}
```

I have confirmed that this happens because of ngIf in which I have wrapped the ngFor div. I have tried to replace the ngIf with `[style.display]="showUpcoming ? 'block' : 'none'"`. But that did not work either.

Comment: You are pushing data into your array.. your should `yourData.concat(NewData)` to your array. Example: `this.upcoming.concat(order)`

Comment: This did not work. The reason why I am being taken to top of content is because ngIf either renders or remove elements from dom based on the condition. concat does not change the current array, but instead returns a new array and if a new array is provided to ngFor, it will render all the content again, and take me to top of content.

Comment: why are your array based on your `ngIf`? your ngIf condition should be seperate from your arrays.

Comment: Because I don't want to display upcoming orders if user has pressed delivered button and vice versa.

Comment: can you make stackblitz example?

Comment: I did solve it, the infinite scrolling worked fine. But when i clicked on any of the two buttons, even without any click handlers, I would be taken to top of screen when I scrolled to bottom. I fixed it by replacing the buttons with paragraphs. Although I don't know why this works.